# How can I get the IMEI no. of my device through ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, imei

I am unable to get IMEI number of my device from my ionic application (android). I tried several ways to do that but failed. How may i suppose to get IMEI number of my device through ionic??

Answer (score 0):

you can use  **imeiplugin**

> install

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/zho/phonegap-imeiplugin.git
```

-- OR --

```
cordova plugin add imeiplugin
```

> Example Usage:

```
window.plugins.imeiplugin.getImei(callback);

 function callback(imei) {
  console.log("My Android IMEI :" + imei);
}
```

for more reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/imeiplugin

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'imeiplugin' of undefined"
this error is showing

Comment: @UsamaIshaque see this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/

Comment: I saw this and also was able to fetch uuid but i just want to get IMEI of my device through ionic not the properties that cordova-plugin-device provides.

Comment: @SanketMendon take a look on `https://github.com/edisonpappi/phonegap-imeiplugin`

Comment: @Edison I tried as it is mentioned in the above link. The android console log gives a Security exception unhandled by the cordova plugin.